# Image filter equivalent in D7?

Tags: 7, media, nodes

I can't seem to get the hang of images in D7.

In D6, I used image and image_filter, which worked very nicely.

The D6 to D7 upgrade converted my image nodes to Node_image, which is useable as far as it goes.

In D7, I'm currently using image (from Drupal core), file entity and insert, (with sources set to existing fields, which requires filefield_sources).

I have tried to add some to book nodes. There are two problems:

1. Linking back to the image node. In structure -> manage -> book -> manage display, the options are "link to content" (which links back to the current book page), "nothing", and "link to file" (which links to the image itself).
2. Displaying the images sanely. The same "manage display" will let me move the images before or after the body of the content. If I have more than one image, they are displayed above each other, not side by side.    I can't see a way to move the image(s) to a different spot *per book page*. If I've understood things correctly, DS will let me put the images eg. in the top right or left corner of the content, nicely wrapped. While that's a step in the right direction, it's not optimal.

I'm sure others have had these same problems. How have you solved them?

(If nothing else, I'll insert the lot by hand, with "img src=" and "a href=", but that's defeating the whole idea of a CMS.)

Referenced modules: http://drupal.org/project/image * http://drupal.org/project/image_filter * http://drupal.org/project/file_entity * http://drupal.org/project/insert * http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources * http://drupal.org/project/ds

[image: What I'm after, from D6]

Comment: I've updated things by hand. Very tedious.